# What is the alternative of "ResolveUsing" in AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 6.0.0

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on **.Net core 2.1** with [AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 6.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/automapper.extensions.microsoft.dependencyinjection/). This is my mapping configuration :

```
CreateMap<User, UserForListDto>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => {
       opt.ResolveUsing(d => d.DateOfBirth.CalculateAge());
});
```

Here `ResolveUsing` is not working, because it is removed or renamed in version `6.0.0`, but it works fine in version `4.0.1`.

I don't find any reference about the changes on their [github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection). Can anybody tell me what is the alternative of `ResolveUsing` in version `6.0.0`?

Issue created [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/84#issue-409118058)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got my answer. In the latest version, we don't need to `ResolveUsing` anymore. There is an overload added to `MapFrom` that serves the purpose of `ResolveUsing`.

```
// Old
CreateMap<User, UserForListDto>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => {
       opt.ResolveUsing(d => d.DateOfBirth.CalculateAge());
});

// New
CreateMap<User, UserForListDto>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => {
       opt.MapFrom(d => d.DateOfBirth.CalculateAge());
});
```

More details [here](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simple replace ResolveUsing with MapFrom Error is kicked out.

```
        CreateMap<User, UserForListDto>()
                       .ForMember(dest => dest.PhotoUrl, opt => {
                           opt.MapFrom(src => src.Photos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.IsMain).Url);
                       }).ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.MapFrom(d => (DateTime.Now - d.DateOfBirth).TotalDays / 365));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).